# performance of a function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there a difference between writing ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in getItems()">
```

and this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
```

let's say getItems looks something like this:

```
$scope.getItems = function() {
  return Object.values(objA).concat(Object.values(objB));
}
```

in the other case, I'll have maintain the array `items` everytime objA and objB change

Comment: yes indeed! the second one will have slight improvement over the first

Comment: @Sajeetharan, how about the performance...

Comment: You won't have much performance issue unless you are dealing with large array

Comment: @Sajeetharan is that because in the first one, the function will run on every `digest` cycle, but in the second it won't?

Comment: yes + you are concating the arrays!

Comment: `ng-repeat` evaluates the expression on every **$digest** cycle, which is often, so the second approach is much better. Just imagine that function would filter your array, then every $digest cycle it would run that filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i commented above, The later one in the question will have a light advantage when you compare with the first one

**`<div ng-repeat="item in items">`**

This will be executed over items which are loaded initially and evaluates expression on every $digest cycle.

**`<div ng-repeat="item in getItems()">`**

Here, you are calling a function which will  get executed manytimes during $digest cycle and you are concatenating the arrays inside the function which is costly when it comes to performance.

Comment: Can you share a link to support what you've stated? Or an example of how was executed that function N times.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique it is from the experience, when i find a link i will add, is there anything wrong?

Comment: Ok, I got it, however, it's good to know about any documentation from AngularJs team. I've never realized about that because I thought that directive will cache it the result of `getItems`. But, like you said, you already have experience with that behavior.  Thanks!

Comment: @EleazarEnrique in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js) you can find that ng-repeat calls `$watchCollection`. Its job is [to _watch_ the properties of some collection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) on every **$digest** cycle, which will require an evaluation of the expression/function

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Perfect! Thank you for sharing!